# Survey code, if statement from another if statement

Tags: python-3.6

I'm making a survey in which I ask a question and if that question is answered with no it should go to that question.

However because it's an if statement on an if statement it gives me the error name is not defined.

It's for a school project in which i need to program a survey, but i cant find a fix on google.

```
   antwoord4 = []
file = open("antwoord4.txt" , "a")

vraagCorrect = True
while vraagCorrect:
  vraag4 = input("Heeft u wel eens iets moeten opzoeken op het internet?(ja/nee) ")
  if vraag4 == "ja":
    vraagCorrect = False
  elif vraag4 == "nee":
    vraagCorrect = False
  else:
    print("Dit is geen correct antwoord, antwoord aub met een ja of nee. ")

antwoord4.append(vraag4)

antwoord41 = []
file = open("antwoord41.txt" , "a")
if vraag4 == "ja":
  vraag41 = input("Waarvoor moest u iets opzoeken?(vrij antwoord)")
  antwoord41.append(vraag41)

file.write(str(antwoord41))
file.write("\n")

antwoord42 =[]
file = open("antwoord42.txt", "a")

if vraag4 == "nee":
  vraagCorrect = True
  while vraagCorrect:
    vraag42 = input("Leest u ooit bronnen op het internet?(ja/nee) ")
    if vraag42 == "ja":
      vraagCorrect = False
    elif vraag42 == "nee":
      vraagCorrect = False
    else:
      print("Dit is geen correct antwoord, gebruik aub ja of nee")
  antwoord42.append(vraag42)
file.write(str(antwoord42))
file.write("\n")

if vraag42 == "nee":
  vraagCorrect = True
  while vraagCorrect:
    vraag1000 = input("Dankuwel, wij hebben alle info die we moeten hebben. U kunt dit tablad sluiten en hoeft deze vraag niet te beantwoorden. ")
    if vraag1000 == "alleen u leest dit dus niemand zal dit invullen":
      vraagCorrect = False
    elif vraag1000 == "Ik vond dit alleen de makkelijkste manier om geen nutteloze antwoorden te krijgen":
      vraagCorrect = False
    else:
      print("\n")
```

I expected it to just be able to be skipped if someone answers yes, but before I reach it the code gives an error that stops the whole survey.

It gives a name 'vraag42' is not defined error.

Comment: Recommended reading: [mcve].  There is missing code so the first error with this sample if ran as shown is `vraag4 is not defined`...the first line. Also provide the full text of the error traceback so it shows what line is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your logic.  This is my best guess because there is missing code and the error traceback wasn't provided to tell what line the error occurred on.  These are the lines that execute if the first `if` is false:

```
if vraag4 == "no":          # assume this is false
  ...                       # skip body of if
file.write(str(antwoord42)) # (missing code, so I assume antwoord42 was defined earlier)
file.write("\n")

if vraag42 == "no":         # vraag42 was defined in the skipped if body, so "not defined error".
```

Comment: I'm sorry, im really new at this. The error occurs on line 128, which is the 15th line here. And two lines i forgot to include that should be all the way in the top are: antwoord42 = [] and below that file = open("antwoord42.txt" , "a" )

Comment: @Joost No problem.  The reason is correct.  Don't test for variables you haven't defined yet.  I can't really restructure your code since the snippet provided doesn't run.

Comment: If you want to check it out, it's in dutch mostly(i translated here) but I made a copy of it on https://repl.it/repls/GlossySunnyOpen64 (a python site)

Comment: I have updated this question so you can see more of the code. It is in its original language now tho.

Comment: I put it into the other if statement and now it works, i didnt expect that and tried before but i did it better this time i guess.